# Maven - Incorrect version dependency

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

My java project relies indirectly on lib:org.ehcache.ehcache. Using both the maven helper plugin and the maven tree command, I see that ehcache version 3.2.3 is dependent. But when I click jump to source, it clearly shows that the indirect dependency is version 3.4.0. Never seen such a strange problem, whose bug is it? maven, ehcache or easyexcel?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vi6oD.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5wdE.png)

mvn dependency:tree shows same result as maven helper plugin, but diff from the sources of the intermediary lib like easyexcel ,all these lib shows their dependency of ehcache are 3.4.0

Comment: solved . spring-boot-dependencies caused my problem.